# What does 'chin-first demeanor' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

The following is from 'The Tiger: A True Story of Vengeance and Survival' by John Vaillant

> Today, even after a serious heart attack, Pikunov still has
>   surprisingly powerful hands-and opinion to match. Among his
>   colleagues, he elicits no neutral feelings, but his **chin-first
>   demeanor** softens when he recalls the man he knew as "Vanya" Dunkai.

What does '**chin-first demeanor**' mean? Is it something to do with Pikunov being a person who elicits no neutral feelings?

Comment: This could be related to the idiom "lead with one's chin" which means to take a risk, or to behave without caution. 

E.g.  Gordon always says exactly what he thinks; he never minds *leading with his chin.*

Comment: A chin thrust forward is part of the iconography of the combative or belligerent personality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phrases like chin-first (or [leading with one's chin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lead+with+one%27s+chin)), [head-first](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/headfirst?s=t) and [feet-first](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feet_first) can mean "with that body part preceding the rest of the body", but usually they are used symbolically.

The "chin" expressions references boxing. If you leave your chin unprotected, it might be easy to knock you out with a single punch, so it can mean either that you're reckless, fearless or aggressive ("I dare you to punch me"). [Taking it on the chin](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+it+on+the+chin) (or nose) can mean that you're tough because you are standing up to a direct punch in the face, which is pretty hard to do.

> She headed chin first into the room full of angry customers, determined to set things right.

The expression "feet-first" references being moved around while laying on a gurney or in a coffin, and can be used to mean "dead".

> The only way I'm leaving this town is feet first!

The expression "head-first" references diving and can mean either reckless or enthusiastic. If you don't [test the waters](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/test+the+waters) (get an idea of what something will be like before you do it),  it can mean you're bold and confident, or it can mean that you're taking a risk that you're going to hit your head because the water is too shallow.

> Excited by the possibilities, he plunged head first into learning how to build mandolins.